# Maven pom can't compile files

Tags: java, maven

I have pom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>AUTOMATION-01</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
    </reporting>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>release-profile</id>

            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I dont understand why I can not compile files from my source directory to output directory.

As the result I have

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building automation 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.104s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 01 15:05:28 MSK 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/72M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But Where all placed can not find < I think it is not generated
Where it will be placed, I would like to have my complied files next and in the same folder with my source files all packed in folder target as example
Where I am wrong?

Comment: Your question is _really_ unclear. Can you give more details? Where do you want to compiled classes to be located? By the way, why are you redefining `sourceDirectory` and such? Just remove those, it is the default value.

Comment: What I have in my pom.xml it does not work becaise I expecting some output folder appears with generated files.

Comment: Do you have any classes to compile under `src/main/java`?

Comment: yes I have pom in the same folder where src folder placed and in src/main/java/ I have pacages like com.prj.utils.*java classes

Answer (score 2):

Your POM specifies `<packaging>` as `pom`. Change it to `jar`.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. How pom impact on this??

Comment: `<packaging>pom</packaging>` is mainly for multi-module builds or specifying a reusable set of dependencies that another POM can import. The packaging basically specifies what the main output (jar, war, ear, etc) of the Maven project should be.